# outlook exchange user details

Tags: active-directory, exchange, outlook

When changing users details in active directory does it take a while for that information to propagate to outlook when clicking on that persons properties?

Because I changed some users information in our AD but when opening outlook and getting his email the properties still show the old information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Exchange 2007 only updates the Global Address List once every 24 hours.  It is scheduled early in the morning (4 or 5 a.m., I think) by default.  Once this task has run within Exchange, your Outlook clients will start getting the property changes as they synchronize their local copies of the Global Address List with Exchange.

Comment: Not entirely true. The GAL is always live. The offline address book is the component you're thinking of. By default it rebuilds daily. You can change that to more frequently.

The important thing here is that your Outlook clients will never grab it more than once in a 24 hour window (unless manually forced).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are looking into offline address book on the client side.
you would got most comprehensive answers in this url

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841273

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the info is coming from the Exchange DSAccess cache. It can take up to 2 hours for Exchange to update the info. I would recommend closing Outlook and checking in about 2 hours for the new info.

Comment: That cache has domain controller info. I'm not aware of it caching directory data...

Comment: No, you're wrong. The dsaccess cache caches configuration data and user data. So change my downvote to an upvote.